# Standard (or convenient) method to read and write tabular data to a text file in c

Tags: c, text, delimiter, tabular

This might sound rather awkward, but I want to ask if there is a commonly practiced way of storing tabular data in a text file to be read and written in C.

Like in python you can load a full text file nto an array by `f.readlines` then go through all the lines and `split` each line by a specific character or sequence of characters (delimiter).

How do you approach this problem in C?

Comment: I've generally just used fprintf and fscanf. For reading in variable length rows, it would also be possible to use fgets and (nested if-need-be) strtok.

Comment: Use a while loop and fscanf/fprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handful of mechanisms, but there's a reason why scripting languages have become so popular over the least twenty years -- some of the tasks that seem simple in scripting languages are ponderous in C.

- You could use [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) and [bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) to write a parser for your tables. This really only works if the format is very well defined and "static". They're amazing tools that can do more than you might suspect, but it is very heavy machinery for what could be done simply with a `split()` in a scripting language.
- You could read individual fields using `getdelim(3)`. However, this was only standardized with POSIX.1-2008, so this is far from ubiquitous. (Every Linux machine with glibc should have them.)
- You could read lines with `fgets(3)` and discover the split locations using `strchr(3)`.
- You could read lines with `fgets(3)` and use `strtok(3)` to tokenize strings.
- You can use `scanf(3)` to perform input and scanning in one go; it seems from the questions here that `scanf(3)` is difficult to use correctly.
- You could use character-at-a-time parsing approaches: read characters using `getc(3)`, inspect it, do something with it, iterate until no more characters.

Comment: @samold thank, so what is the reason there are no nice libraries to do these very useful string manipulations, written in C?

Comment: Perhaps there are -- there are thousands of little libraries out there, after all -- but the configuration of which delimiters are used between which fields and what data structures to create with the strings might be easier to just hand-write as you need them. `scanf(3)` is supposed to be helpful in this area, perhaps I've just become jaded about it after seeing a great many Stackers have trouble using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same way you would in any other language. Pick a field separator (I.E., `tab` character), open the text file for reading and parse each line.

Of course, in `C` it will never be as easy as it is in `Python`, but approaches are similar.

Answer (score 2):

Whoa. I am a bit baffled by the other answers which make me feel like I'm on Mainframes.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow.com

Why don't you pick a modern data format like JSON or XML and follow best practices for the data format of your choice?

If you want a good JSON reader/writer for C, I've used [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/), and it's very easy and fast.

If you want a good XML reader/writer for C, I've used [miniXML](http://www.minixml.org/) and it's also easy and fast. Also has SAX *and * DOM support depending on how you want to read in the XML.

Obviously there are a wealth of other libraries available as well.

Please don't give the next guy to come along and support your program some wacky custom file format to deal with.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I would be dealing with rather large datasets, and I don't want to get sucked into memory or performance problems, but I guess using json with a well written library should be good enough for me.

Comment: And you would be comfortable inflicting _XML_ on your next user? No thanks. JSON is alright, I can't complain about that too much. :)

Comment: @sarnold- XML definitely has its place - especially in corporate land where handing off a schema which clearly defines available and required fields, data types, max lengths, etc can be very desirable, and where mature well developed tool chains exist to transfer, process, and transform the data. JSON is extremely useful in many situations as well - but it's not a replacement for XML per se. I don't think it's fair to compare them the way you have with blanket statements.

Comment: @ali - obviously XML, JSON, and company, aren't always a viable replacement for a custom binary format - especially if your product revolves around data manipulation (if you are developing SQL Server I probably wouldn't suggest using JSON... Although mongoDB seems to have done pretty well). But it strikes me that the VAST majority of people who think they can't take on the "performance overhead" of a well structured and documented file format standard like XML or JSON are simply optimizing far earlier than need be. A good XML parser with SAX support can usually rip through XML documents.

Comment: Hrm, the `@sarnold-` didn't actually notify me of the new message. I suggest switching to [`,` or `:`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). You're right, I was too glib with my blanket statement, but I've gone blind trying to find errors in XML documents before, and hooking up a full-blown SAX parser to try to parse documents into something human-readable seems counter-productive to designing a human-readable input format in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I find [`getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) and [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to be quite convenient (`getline` was a gnu extension, standardized in POSIX.1-2008).